# What are all scenario's that can cause a 'Broker not available error' when using kafka-node npm

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing a problem with kafka-node npm as I had made a producer for kafka using kafka-node npm and recently sometimes it gives me errors i.e "Broker Not Available", I looked into it and everything seems fine and I am not able to figure out whats going wrong. So if anyone can suggest me some options regarding any timeout or other issues that my occur..?

```
function (topic, pload, isBatchProducer) {
     var HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer;
     if(isBatchProducer) {
        var client = new kafka.Client(E.config.zookeeperServer, C.CLIENTID, {}, C.NO_ACK_BATCH_PRODUCER_OPTIONS);
        producer = new HighLevelProducer(client, {requireAcks: 0});
     } 
     else {
        var client = new kafka.Client(E.config.zookeeperServer, C.CLIENTID);
        producer = new HighLevelProducer(client);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the high level producers shouldn't be using Zookeeper, so either the variable is named wrong, or you've not actually given a broker.

But the error itself is usually caused by a network misconfiguration, such as firewalls or misunderstanding of `advertised.listeners` setting or the broker is actually offline, in my experience